# How to load custom Jquery libraries in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a bootstrap theme called [Reen](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/reen-made-for-designers-one-multi-page-WB00PN23G) with Wordpress and have been learning how to make a Wordpress theme with it. I've got a little stuck getting the required jQuery libraries to load within wordpress (the theme uses quite a few) and I'm wondering if I am loading them correctly using `wp_enqueue_scripts` or am I way off? I don't think they are loading as when I check with firebug I only see blank code when I use the script inspector. Any advice greatly appreciated.

function.php

```
<?php 

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );

    wp_register_script( 'custom-script2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script2' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/skrollr.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script3' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/skrollr.stylesheets.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script4' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/waypoints.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script5' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script6', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/waypoints-sticky.min', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script6' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/reen/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script7' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script8' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: The code seems correct at the first glance. Can you check if the <script ...> tags are added in the HTML? I.e. open the View Page Source and try searching for the references to your scripts — are they there?

Comment: Yes, they seem to be there in the header with script tags so perhaps it's something else. Thanks.

Comment: With firebug I can see this error 'Access to restricted URI denied' with each library I'm trying to load so I guess there is clue there...not sure what.

Comment: Can you please give complete URLs that are output in the generated HTML? If you want to keep the name of your site name secret, please replace it with example.org; other parts of the URLs would help, too.

Comment: This seems related to the "same origins policy'. Is the URL you are accessing these files the same you have configured for WP?

Comment: It suddenly seems to be working, the scripts are working (still get the access restricted message though). I think there was a page refresh issue. Thanks for the encouragement, I would have given up otherwise.